# How do I remove the 'Show Toolbar' option?

Tags: profiles, admin-bar

I'm using the following code to hide the admin toolbar in the front end:
`add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );`

But how do I hide this option in wp-admin?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to hide it with CSS:

```
add_action( 'personal_options', function( $profileuser )
{
    ?><style>.show-admin-bar{ display: none;}</style><?php
} );
```

or rather place it within the `<head>...</head>` with:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-user-edit.php', 'wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings' );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-profile.php',   'wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings' );

function wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings()
{
    ?><style>.show-admin-bar{ display: none;}</style><?php
}
```

You could perhaps add your own `wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings` filter if you need more control:

```
function wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings()
{
    if( (bool) apply_filters( 'wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings', false ) )
        echo '<style>.show-admin-bar{ display: none;}</style>';
}
```

and then turn it off/on with:

```
add_filter( 'wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings', '__return_false' ); // show it
add_filter( 'wpse_hide_admin_bar_settings', '__return_true' );  // hide it
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work. Although one would think that when you disable this in the frontend, this option would at least be disabled backend.

Comment: If I understand your comment, Steven: a) The "Show Toolbar" option is something a user might want to enable some times and disable other times. If unchecking the option in the dashboard removed it from the dashboard, there's no way to re-enable it. b) Quite curious: why do you want to remove this feature?